# Angular 2 Promises or RxJs?

Tags: angular, rxjs, es6-promise

Looking at RxJs, they seem more powerful, but we have been using Promises so far to do the Ajax in angular applicaitons.

Which one is preferred approach in Angular 2 applications? Do we ever need to include ES6 promise polyfill when using RxJs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be used together, which works very good. RxJS is not only for resolving promises, but for async application flows. You can use [Rx.Observable.fromPromise](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md) to create an Observable which emits one element, when the promise is resolved.

Here is an example:

```
// Create a promise which resolves 42
var promise1 = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve(42);
});

var source1 = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise1);

var subscription1 = source1.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Next: 42
// => Completed

// Create a promise which rejects with an error
var promise2 = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    reject(new Error('reason'));
});

var source2 = Rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise2);

var subscription2 = source2.subscribe(
  function (x) {
    console.log('Next: %s', x);
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

// => Error: Error: reject
```

For an angular 2 demo with RxJS, have a look at [angular2-rxjs-chat](https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat)